# Checkbox returns "on", ActiveRecord needs "true"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, boolean

I have a form, where I defined a vanilla html checkbox

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargeForm' do %>
  (...)
  <input type="checkbox" id="agreed_to_terms" name="agreed_to_terms" /><label class="inputclass" for="agreed_to_terms">Agree to Terms</label>
<% end %>
```

model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  (...)
  validates_acceptance_of :agreed_to_terms
```

When POST, the params:

```
"agreed_to_terms"=>"on"}
```

controller

```
  if charge["paid"]
    @product.update(status: "sold",
                    email:      params[:email],
                    first_name: params[:first_name],
                    last_name:  params[:last_name]
                    agreed_to_terms: params[:agreed_to_terms])
```

Transaction rollsback.

ActiveRecord says it needs to be true or false, not on or off.

How do I get this to work without doing this

```
  if charge["paid"]
    @product.update(status: "sold",
                    email:      params[:email],
                    first_name: params[:first_name],
                    last_name:  params[:last_name]
    @product.update_attribute(:agreed_to_terms, "true")
```

Which is wrong for so many reasons

Comment: Please post the `form code`.

Answer (score 1):

To go in details I need your form code, but for a quick fix you can do this

```
agreed_to_terms: (params[:agreed_to_terms].eql?('on') ? true : false)
```

or

In your form add the following lines instead of `<input type="checkbox" id="agreed_to_terms" name="agreed_to_terms" />`

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "agreed_to_terms", false %>
<%= check_box_tag "agreed_to_terms", checked = true %>
```

When the checkbox is unchecked it will pass `false`, `true` otherwise

Comment: Edited my answer, try it out

Comment: why is there a hidden field ?

Comment: It is required when the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: I don't understand `it will pass false, true otherwise`

Comment: Also, I have very basic styling for my checkbox, and this solution kills my styling for the checkbox when it's checked, so I can't know whether I have it checked or not. Furthermore, does `checked = true` mean it is checked, or does it mean you are assigning the value `true` to the parameter checked @rsb

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem in the rails console, setting `agreed_to_terms` to all of the following

`t`
`"t"`
`true`
`"true"`
`1`
`"1"`
`accepted`
`"accepted"`

to no avail.

Turns out, for some odd reason, I needed to specify in the validation what value the field should accept

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  (...)
  validates_acceptance_of :agreed_to_terms, accept: true
```